# PyOpenCL - Different results on Intel and NVidia

Tags: python, numpy, opencl, nvidia, pyopencl

I'm trying to run a simulation that is based on gaussian pulses propagation. I'm cross developing between my windows desktop with an i5 4590 & GTX 970 (latest drivers) and my early 2015 macbook air.

When running my main code i couldn't get any decent results on my desktop (the calculations diverged) but on my mac the results seemed ok.

To investigate the problem further I've tried to run a simples gaussian propagation. The results on the macbook are more or less ok, while on the desktop it's a complete mess.

I'm running the same code on both machines and both have the same distribution of python (2.7.10) and the respective modules.

Here is my code

```
import scipy as sp
import pyopencl as cl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

dx = 0.01
X = sp.arange(0.0, 100, dx)
N = len(X)

A_h = (sp.exp(-(X-50)**2/10.)*sp.exp(-1j*1000*X)).astype(sp.complex64)
A_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=A_h)

plot.figure()
plot.plot(X, abs(A_h) ** 2 / (abs(A_h) ** 2).max())

Source = """
    #define complex_ctr(x, y) (float2)(x, y)
    #define complex_mul(a, b) complex_ctr(mad(-(a).y, (b).y, (a).x * (b).x), mad((a).y, (b).x, (a).x * (b).y))
    #define complex_unit (float2)(0, 1)

    __kernel void propagate(__global float2 *A){
        const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
        float EPS = 0.1f;
        A[gid_x] = A[gid_x] + EPS*complex_mul((A[gid_x+1] + A[gid_x-1]), complex_unit);
    }
"""
prg = cl.Program(ctx, Source).build()
for i in range(3000):
    print i
    event = prg.propagate(queue, (N,), None, A_d)
    event.wait()
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, A_h, A_d)

plot.plot(X, abs(A_h) ** 2 / (abs(A_h) ** 2).max())

plot.show()
```

And here are the results

Desktop result:
[image: Desktop result]

Mac result:

[image: Mac result]

Green line corresponds to the gaussian after propagation and the Blue line is the initial gaussian

What may cause this issue on the NVidia side? I think i'm missing a crucial step to prevent this from happening and that it runs on the mac somewhat due to luck

*EDIT*

This is my final code that is working based on the user's suggestions

```
import scipy as sp
import pyopencl as cl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

dx = sp.float32(0.001)
X = sp.arange(0.0, 100, dx).astype(sp.float32)
N = len(X)

A_h = (sp.exp(-(X-50)**2/10.)*sp.exp(1j*1000*X)).astype(sp.complex64)
A_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=A_h)
B_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=A_h)

plot.figure()
plot.plot(X, abs(A_h) ** 2 / (abs(A_h) ** 2).max())

Source = """
    #define complex_ctr(x, y) (float2)(x, y)
    #define complex_mul(a, b) complex_ctr((a).x * (b).x - (a).y * (b).y, (a).x * (b).y + (a).y * (b).x)
    #define complex_unit (float2)(0, 1)

    __kernel void propagate(__global float2 *A){
        const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
        float EPS = 0.1f;
        float2 a1, a2;
        a1 = A[gid_x-1];
        a2 = A[gid_x+1];
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
        A[gid_x] += EPS*complex_mul((a1 + a2), complex_unit);
    }
"""

prg = cl.Program(ctx, Source).build()
for i in range(12000):
    print i
    evolve = prg.propagate(queue, (N,), None, A_d)
    evolve.wait()
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, A_h, A_d)

plot.plot(X, abs(A_h) ** 2)

plot.show()
```

Comment: Your kernel is completely broken. You have memory races in the calculation of `A`. Change the kernel so that the calculations are not performed in-place and you might have more luck

Comment: @talonmies Sorry, I'm not sure I understood what you said. By memory races you mean that I should use atomics?

Comment: You have different threads attempting to read from and write to the same memory locations in `A` simultaneously. That is a read-after-write hazard or race.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks. That's what I meant with atomic operations. I'll do some research on how to prevent this.

Is there any issue trying to access the indexes -1 or N? Will it just assume 0 or a random value? This is important in my case for reflective boundary conditions.
Sorry for all the questions

Comment: When I replied, your comment included nothing about atomics, it was just cut off . But no, you don't need atomics for this. Use two arrays in the kernel, one as an input, one as an output, and switch them between iterations in the python code (and switching doesn't imply performing a copy in this case).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the reply.
Your solution worked, thank you. As I said bellow, I tried also using a memory fence which also worked

Comment: The memory fence works out of pure luck. It is also not safe. CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE does not propagate across work-groups. You also have errors, but they are just small (boundaries of work-groups) and you didn't notice them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT: oh, just read @talonmies comment, it is same solution as this.*

This code is not safe in OpenCL, it has datarace problem:

```
A[gid_x] = A[gid_x] + EPS*complex_mul((A[gid_x+1] + A[gid_x-1]), complex_unit);
```

Every work item `x` uses `x+1` and `x-1`. Depending on the schedule of work items the result will be different.

Use 2 buffers instead, read from A, write to B, easy:

```
import scipy as sp
import pyopencl as cl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

dx = 0.01
X = sp.arange(0.0, 100, dx)
N = len(X)

A_h = (sp.exp(-(X-50)**2/10.)*sp.exp(-1j*1000*X)).astype(sp.complex64)
A_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=A_h)
B_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE)

plot.figure()
plot.plot(X, abs(A_h) ** 2 / (abs(A_h) ** 2).max())

Source = """
    #define complex_ctr(x, y) (float2)(x, y)
    #define complex_mul(a, b) complex_ctr(mad(-(a).y, (b).y, (a).x * (b).x), mad((a).y, (b).x, (a).x * (b).y))
    #define complex_unit (float2)(0, 1)

    __kernel void propagate(__global float2 *A, __global float2 *B){
        const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
        float EPS = 0.1f;
        B[gid_x] = A[gid_x] + EPS*complex_mul((A[gid_x+1] + A[gid_x-1]), complex_unit);
    }
"""
prg = cl.Program(ctx, Source).build()
for i in range(3000):
    print i
    event = prg.propagate(queue, (N,), None, A_d, B_d)
    A_d, B_d = B_d, A_d #Swap buffers, so A always has results
    #event.wait() #You don't need this, this is slowing terribly the execution, enqueue_copy already waits
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, A_h, A_d)

plot.plot(X, abs(A_h) ** 2 / (abs(A_h) ** 2).max())

plot.show()
```

Comment: This worked. I also learned about memory fences and that seems to be working also.

Comment: No, you cannot use memory fences in the case you posted. Not even atomics. In fact no method is possible to solve the issue, since you write and read from the same memory location, and your algorithm depends on the work items work in-order. The only solution is to create another memory region.

Comment: Oh ok. Maybe that explains why when I'm trying to propagate for more iterations, the errors appear again with the memory fences. What do you mean by creating a different memory region? Is it the method you suggested? I'm not familiar with the terms, sorry.

Comment: In the code I posted, I create a memory B, with is the output of each iteration. Then I swap A with B (only the pointers) in each iteration. Using 2 memory zones avoids the problem of reading and writing to the same locations.